# Customize ASP.NET MVC MapRoute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, maproute

Default ASP.NET MVC project has one MapRoute like

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
            );
```

And urls like these are equivalent: **www.mysite.com**, **www.mysite.com/home**, **www.mysite.com/home/index**

But if I trying to use a MapRoute like

```
            routes.MapRoute(
            "Sitemap",
            "{controller}/{action}",
            new { controller = "Sitemap", action = "ShortMap" }
        );
```

and test url **www.mysite.com/sitemap** I recieve error 404 but I'm expecting that it's work like **www.mysite.com/sitemap/shortmap**

How to write this MapRoute correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best thing I have found to aid in map route issues is Phil Haack's route tool http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx.  It's a great way to see which and how your routes are being used.

What happens when you try /sitemap/action

Answer (score 1):

You should probably spell the word controller correctly.

You have it spelled `contoller`

Comment: Just mistake in question not in code.
I solved the problem by this code:

routes.MapRoute(
                "MainPage",
                "",
                new { controller="Home", action="Index" }
                );

routes.MapRoute(
                "Sitemap",
                "Sitemap/{action}",
                new { controller = "Sitemap", action = "ShortMap" }
                );

Now www.mysite.com/sitemap and www.mysite.com/sitemap/shortmap are equivalent. It was not work because of the default MapRoute influnce.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the view "ShortMap" really exists. I know, it's simple - but happened to me a few times.